# Problem with Ionic back button component not being resolved by Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic4, vuejs3

I cannot achieve to find out why I'm getting this warning from Vue, and the back button is not working:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: ion-back-button 
  at <TheHeader titulo="Home" > 
  at <IonPage isInOutlet=true registerIonPage=fn<registerIonPage> > 
  at <Home ref=Ref< undefined > key="/home" isInOutlet=true  ... > 
  at <IonRouterOutlet> 
  at <IonApp> 
  at <App>
```

It's a simple app from scratch with some pages sharing a header, which I'm trying to outsource in a new component called TheHeader. Since then, the back button no longer works.

I'm trying to skip unnecessary code to get to the point quicker.
This is one of my pages, **Home.vue**:

```html
<template>
    <ion-page>
        <the-header titulo="Home"></the-header>
        <ion-content>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import { IonContent, IonPage } from '@ionic/vue';
import TheHeader from '../components/TheHeader.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    IonContent,
    IonPage,
    'the-header': TheHeader
  }
};
</script>
```

This is my **TheHeader.vue** component:

```html
<template>
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-buttons name="start">
                <ion-back-button>
                </ion-back-button>
            </ion-buttons>
            <ion-title>
                {{ titulo }}
            </ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
</template>

<script>
import { IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonButtons, IonBackButton } from '@ionic/vue'

export default {
    props: [
        'titulo'
    ],
    components: [
        IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonButtons, IonBackButton
    ]
}
</script>
```

Well, if I navigate from Home to another page, which is basically similar (I'm using a very basic nav menu within ion-content), or even if I reload this page, so no navigation at all, I get the above warning, and in case I navigate to another page, and then I click on the back button, the previous page is not loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#components) specify that the type is only `Object`. And this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/components-as-array-does-not-work-5kcr8?file=/src/App.vue) shows that arrays cannot be used for `components`.

The solution is to change `components` into an `Object` in `TheHeader.vue`:

```js
export default {
    // BEFORE:
    components: [ IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonButtons, IonBackButton ]

    // AFTER:                                                             
    components: { IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonButtons, IonBackButton }
}
```